# Table without unnecessary whitespaces

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, tabu, tabulary

First of all, I'm not quite sure how to properly put my issue into words, let alone caption it, so I'm sorry if the title is slightly misleading.

I think it's the easiest to describe by the following example:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,tabulary,tabu}

\begin{document}


\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {X[-0.5]X[1]X[1]}
c1 & c2 & c3 \\ \toprule
c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 &c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 & c3\\
              & c2-2 should continue w/o whitespace above & c3-2 \\
              & c2-3 & c3-3 \\
              & c2-4  & c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 \\ 
              & c2-5 should continue w/o whitespace above & \\
c1-6          & c2-6 & c3-6 \\
\end{longtabu}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Basically, I want `c2` to be "continuous" when possible (i. e. when `c1` and `c3` are empty). Any ideas? :)

Comment: so why put the cells into separate rows at all then?

Comment: @Thruston Well, I still want the linebreak. I just don't want the space afterwards. Frankly, I'm still struggling a bit with LaTeX tables, what would you recommend?

Comment: It is hard to guess what you want just from the example, you are forcing c2-2 to be in the next row of the table, if you want c2-2 to be continuous from c2 just put it after c2  in the same cell (leaving a blank line if you want it in a new paragraph)

Comment: @theCed7: Is the use of `longtabu` or `longtable` necessary here? Are you willing to change your input to achieve the output?

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you want can be done with `multirow`, but it will require some hand-tuning. For example with the default setup of `multirow` (`\multirowsetup=\raggedright`, the fifth `c3` row would overflow to the sixth, so you would have to add an additional row to set row 6 free.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,tabulary,tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\multirowsetup}{} % not \raggedright
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {X[-0.5]X[1]X[1]}
c1 & c2 & c3 \\ \toprule
\multirow[t]{2}={c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1} &c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 & c3\\
              & c2-2 should continue w/o whitespace above & c3-2 \\
              & c2-3 & c3-3 \\
              & c2-4  & \multirow[t]{2}={c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4} \\ 
              & c2-5 should continue w/o whitespace above & \\
c1-6          & c2-6 & c3-6 \\
\end{longtabu}    
\end{document}
```

Here with the default multirow setup, causing overflow:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,tabulary,tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {X[-0.5]X[1]X[1]}
c1 & c2 & c3 \\ \toprule
\multirow[t]{2}={c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1 c1} &c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 c2 & c3\\
              & c2-2 should continue w/o whitespace above & c3-2 \\
              & c2-3 & c3-3 \\
              & c2-4  & \multirow[t]{2}={c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4 c3-4} \\ 
              & c2-5 should continue w/o whitespace above & \\
              \\ % extra row
c1-6          & c2-6 & c3-6 \\
\end{longtabu}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note you need the newest version of `multirow` for these examples to work.